Почему на старые ответы ставят минусы?
Почему на старые ответы ставят минусы? Похоже, что это ненормальное явление, если ответ был опубликован был принят автором и получил голоса "за". Зачем такой ответ минусовать? Это что из-за личной неприязни или месть? Вот примеры моих ответов, которые получили минус(в) после их принятия как правильный ответ:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/838230/204920
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/837449/204920
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1594482/204920
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/878258/204920
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1586189/204920
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/861103/204920
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836681/204920

И это не весь список, минусы ставят на старые ответы. Что мне делать?

Если голосование массовое, система автоматически его отменит. Срок от часа до суток.

@Мод Что такое массовое? Это 5 или более, а если одно два, то как? Мне уже понаставляли за последние полгода минусов на вопросы и на ответы из-за неприязни, хотя голосование анонимное, но это не работает.

@RomanC разберитесь уже у кого с кем неприязнь https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/14377/1365. Санта-Барбара какая-то.

получили минус(в) после их принятия как правильный ответ => у меня есть принятые ответы тоже с минусами, разве минус и принятый ответ связанны? //минусует сообщество принимает ТС

Критерии определения массового голосования не раскрываются.

@Dev18 Это смотря кто ставит минус, если мы не знаем это, то трудно сказать, что минусы были от одного и того же человека. А так же трудно сказать, какова мотивация была у этого человека,когда он ставил минусы на старые ответы. Система не работает правильно, поэтому я задал этот вопрос, может он поможет этот сайт сделать лучше.

@Мод Даже если они не раскрываются, то емпирическим путем, можно это вычислить.

@aepot, а если допустим я знаю, если я раскрою эту информацию, мне что-то плохое за это будет?)

@RomanC, это замечательно, что вы хотите сделать сайт лучше, а также обращаете внимание на качество вопросов/ответов. У меня вам личная просьба, если вы ставите минусы, пишите причину, таким образом мы двух зайцев поймаем, 1. Отвечающий исправит ответ, либо переубедит вас, что его ответ правильный 2. Сайт станет лучше и ответы станут качественней✅

@Dev18 Это не является обязательным, и вопрос касается минусов на старые ответы. И поскольку этот вопрос уже заминусован, то , он не является полезным, и будет удален (Вместе со всеми этими комментариями).

Роман, обязательным может и не быть, но значительно улучшит качество вопросов/ответов (чего вы и хотите) благодаря вашему вкладу, просто написав комментарий каждый раз, когда вы ставите минус...//а удалят этот вопрос или нет (вместе с комментариями) совершенно не важно, ведь диалог между мной и вами

@insolor есть только один способ выяснить :)

@RomanC только что был такой-же вопрос в вашу сторону. "Это что из-за личной неприязни или месть?". Может быть правда месть.

@Dev18 Качество вопросов и ответов это не улучшит. Изначально было задумано, что так будет, но потом закидали плохими вопросами и ответами так, что на них никто не стал отвечать. В результате комментарии писать перестали, чтобы не отнимали драгоценное время. Но мой вопрос не о том. Я ставлю минусы на новые ответы, независимо от их качества. Главным критерием является правильность, полнота и краткость, содержательность, корректность, а размер символов в посте меня как-то мало волнует.  Но если  минусы тебе ставят на старые и принятые ответы, то это становится проблемой.

@RomanC,на ru.SO нет новых или старых вопросов. Если я на сайте впервые ищу что то, то ответ на это для меня новый. Надо понимать, что база ответов/вопросов просматривается постоянно. Если я на старом ответе нашла себе решение, то я ставлю плюс и также обратно. А то, что вы про драгоценное время упомянул, так и ru.SO дорогой нам ресурс. Лучше минус с комментарием, чем обида/выяснение отношений/блокировка ценой тишины... Ваши высказывания несколько противоречивы, я слышу только, что вы видите только свою правду.

Также добавлю, и вам меня не переубедить, что среди новых ответом есть много качественных ровно столько же сколько среди старых бесполезных...

Лучше давайте вместе улучшать, ваши знания могут помочь новому поколению.

@Dev18 Думаю, что неправильно вас понял. Вы сказали, что "диалог между мной и вами",  но теперь вы говорите совсем другое - "вам меня не переубедить". Тогда, я думаю, что нет смысла продолжать этот диалог. Вы говорите ю, что "на ru.SO нет новых или старых вопросов", но это не так, есть дата/время создания, когда был задан вопрос, остальные все действия также зафиксированы по времени, и от этой даты надо считать возраст.

@Dev18 Если вопрос/ответ был создан несколько лет назад, то такие вопросы я называю старыми, независимо от того кто их видит новыми для себя, я не хочу вести с вами демагогию, потому что вы рассматриваете все мои утверждения со своей точки зрения, а не объективно. Поэтому, лучше прекратить с вами этот диалог.

@Dev18 Вынужден признать это, что это невозможно. А вопрос, может и будет полезным, но пока непонятно, что с этим делать.

Кажется я понял, что можно с этим сделать. Нужно просто заблокировать старые ответы на голоса после истечения определенного срока жизни. Это можно, также ввести и для старых вопросов, пока этот вопрос/ответ не будет отредактирован. Наподобие того, как это сделано для отмены голосования или повторного голосования.

Stack Overflow — это платформа, где главной целью является качество вопросов и ответов. Ответы оцениваются сообществом на основе их актуальности, точности и полезности, и важно понимать, что минусы могут появляться спустя время не из-за "личной неприязни", а из-за того, что:

Ответы теряют актуальность. Со временем могут появляться новые технологии, методы или стандарты, которые делают старые ответы устаревшими.

Ответы могут быть неполными или содержать ошибки. Иногда пользователи, пересматривая старые ответы, замечают, что они могли бы быть лучше объяснены, более полными или содержат ошибки, которых раньше не замечали.

Качество со временем становится более важным. Сообщество Stack Overflow постоянно растёт, и новые пользователи, приходя на сайт, могут пересматривать старые ответы и оценивать их с других точек зрения. Это нормально.


Стоит также учесть, (в данном контексте (!!!) => (понятно, что если брать дату создания, то один вопрос/ответ может считаться "старше" другого. Однако для голосований подобное разделение не имеет значения, иначе можно было бы считать некорректным и редактирование, и голоса "за"...), что для новых участников платформы нет "старых" или "новых" вопросов/ответов — есть просто вопросы и ответы. Например, если пользователь пришёл на сайт сегодня и нашёл решение в ответе, который был опубликован несколько лет назад, для него этот ответ будет новым, ведь он видит его впервые. Минусование ответов не зависит от их "возраста", и если пользователи считают, что информация в ответе устарела или недостаточно полезна, они могут выразить своё мнение через систему голосования.
Важно отметить, что минусование — это не атака на личность. Да, процесс анонимный, и бывают ситуации, когда может казаться, что минусы ставятся из-за личных мотивов, но это скорее исключение, чем правило. Важно не фокусироваться на каждом минусе, а на том, что именно можно улучшить в ответах, чтобы они лучше служили сообществу.
И, как вы правильно отметили в своих комментариях, сайт становится лучше, когда люди дают обратную связь. Если вы видите минусы, возможно, это сигнал пересмотреть свои ответы и адаптировать их к новым требованиям времени. Минус с комментарием действительно был бы полезен, но, к сожалению, это не является обязательным на Stack Overflow. Тем не менее, если вы видите недостатки в других ответах, вы можете всегда оставить комментарий с предложением исправить их.
Вместе с сообществом мы можем улучшить качество ответов и помочь новым пользователям получать актуальную и полезную информацию. И я верю, что если вас действительно заботит развитие сайта, а не просто количество минусов, то вы также будете оставлять комментарии под теми ответами, которым ставите минусы. Это поможет авторам пересмотреть свои ответы, а сайту — стать лучше.
Важно помнить, что начинать надо с себя. Только вместе мы создаём и улучшаем ru.SO.

"если пользователь пришёл на сайт сегодня и нашёл решение в ответе, который был опубликован несколько лет назад, для него этот ответ будет новым" - это неверное предположение. У ответа есть дата создания, и возраст измеряется относительно этой даты.

Улучшить работу сайта можно, если внести изменения в программное обеспечение. Этот вопрос скорее будет полезен разработчикам, нежели пользователям. Поскольку пользователи не могут ничего сделать, а модераторы просто "машут ручкой".

@RomanC Как пользователь, я не часто смотрю на дату написания ответа, если этот ответ меня удовлетворяет. Вот если ответ не один, спорен или неоднозначен, то да - смотрю на репутацию отвечающего и на дату.

@Kromster Речь идёт об ответах, написанных значительно раньше текущей даты. Такие ответы я называю старыми.
